# Why does a positively correlated variable have a negative coefficient in a multiple regression?

Tags: correlation, multiple-regression, confidence-interval

Please help me understand what a negative confidence interval actually means and how it can be interpreted, especially when the variable has a positive correlation with the dependent variable. Below is the data and its structure.

```
'data.frame':   251 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ BodyFat: num  12.3 6.1 25.3 10.4 28.7 20.9 19.2 12.4 4.1 11.7 ...
 $ Weight : num  154 173 154 185 184 ...
 $ Chest  : num  93.1 93.6 95.8 101.8 97.3 ...
 $ Abdomen: num  85.2 83 87.9 86.4 100 94.4 90.7 88.5 82.5 88.6 ...
 $ Hip    : num  94.5 98.7 99.2 101.2 101.9 ...
 $ Thigh  : num  59 58.7 59.6 60.1 63.2 66 58.4 60 62.9 63.1 ...
 $ Biceps : num  32 30.5 28.8 32.4 32.2 35.7 31.9 30.5 35.9 35.6 ...

> cor(body) # Shows positive correlation values between variables.
          BodyFat    Weight     Chest   Abdomen       Hip     Thigh    Biceps
BodyFat 1.0000000 0.6199217 0.7009325 0.8253710 0.6384826 0.5568926 0.4821925
Weight  0.6199217 1.0000000 0.8913628 0.8742672 0.9294444 0.8505810 0.7851911
Chest   0.7009325 0.8913628 1.0000000 0.9098518 0.8207654 0.7055343 0.7072069
Abdomen 0.8253710 0.8742672 0.9098518 1.0000000 0.8593542 0.7379840 0.6564326
Hip     0.6384826 0.9294444 0.8207654 0.8593542 1.0000000 0.8837342 0.7173519
Thigh   0.5568926 0.8505810 0.7055343 0.7379840 0.8837342 1.0000000 0.7401922
Biceps  0.4821925 0.7851911 0.7072069 0.6564326 0.7173519 0.7401922 1.0000000

> summary(fitb)

Call:
lm(formula = BodyFat ~ Weight + Chest + Abdomen + Hip + Thigh + 
    Biceps, data = body)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-10.7135  -3.1515  -0.1814   3.3503  10.1434 

Coefficients:
             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -52.28196    9.30962  -5.616 5.31e-08 ***
Weight       -0.16593    0.03811  -4.354 1.97e-05 ***
Chest        -0.04360    0.09863  -0.442    0.659    
Abdomen       1.01866    0.07489  13.603  < 2e-16 ***
Hip          -0.07026    0.14124  -0.497    0.619    
Thigh         0.21373    0.13010   1.643    0.102    
Biceps        0.17409    0.16184   1.076    0.283    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 4.372 on 244 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.7317,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.7251 
F-statistic: 110.9 on 6 and 244 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Below i get a negative confidence interval for Weight, which had positive correlation in the first place.

What does that actually mean? Please help me interpret this.

```
> confint(fitb)
                  2.5 %      97.5 %
(Intercept) -70.6194423 -33.9444834
Weight       -0.2409986  -0.0908677
Chest        -0.2378653   0.1506702
Abdomen       0.8711559   1.1661630
Hip          -0.3484608   0.2079337
Thigh        -0.0425293   0.4699805
Biceps       -0.1446869   0.4928583
```

Comment: nothing strange about having negative coefficients for independent variables for a linear regression.

Comment: I cannot see any thing wrong with your results or your code. If your remove other variables from your model, particularly `Abdomen`, you would get a positive coefficient and 95% CIs for `weight`.

Comment: @AdamQuek What I was looking for is an interpretation. "with 95% confidence we can say that 1 % increase in Weight increases (or decreases?) the BodyFat from -0.2409986  -0.0908677 " But Weight has a positive correlation with Bodyfat, not negative !

Comment: @Alexandregeorges I'm afraid your statement doesnt make sense. As i said in the question, weight already has a 'positive' correlation with BodyFat. i.e increase in weight increases bodyfat. Then why a negetive value for confint ?

Comment: @Salih the negative coefficient of weight might seem counterintuitive to you, but it means the following: _holding all other variables constant_, an increase in weight by one pound is associated with a decrease of 0.24 percentage points in body fat. I think it is key for you to understand what _holding all other variables constant_ means. As is evident in the correlation matrix you present, `Abdomen` and `Weight` are also highly correlated. After partialing out the effects of these two highly correlated predictors on `Bodyfat`, it appears the effect of belly circumference...

Comment: ... is also what drives the correlation between `Weight` and `Bodyfat`. If you separate the effect from `Abdomen` from that correlation, you get a negative coefficient. It makes sense, too: When you partial out the effect of, colloquially speaking, belly fat on weight, increasing weight is likely driven by muscle tissue. And, muscle tissue, of course, directly decreases your proportion of bodyfat

Comment: Besides what @mkt has answered, your explanatory variables seem to be highly correlated. So weight may be have high positive correlation because Bodyfat may be positive correlation with other things which also are positively correlated with Weight. This appears to be hiding the negative independent correlation between Weight and Bodyfat. In time series this is something like ACF of AR1 giving positive correlations at more than one lag.

Comment: @tifu Thanks very much !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98092/discussion-on-question-by-salih-why-does-a-positively-correlated-variable-have-a).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are comparing two very different things. In the first case, you are making pairwise comparisons when calculating the correlation coefficient between BodyFat and Weight. In the second, you are doing a multiple regression that also accounts for the variation in BodyFat that is explained by all your other variables.

To oversimplify a bit: after accounting for the variation explained by the other variables, the relationship between Weight and BodyFat is negative. Since if you ignore the other variables, the relationship is positive, this implies that Weight covaries with one or more of the other variables (which you can also see in the correlation matrix). You can see that Abdomen is strongly positively correlated with both Weight ($r$ = 0.87) and BodyFat ($r$ = 0.83), so it is plausible that accounting for Abdomen undid the positive relationship between Weight and BodyFat.

If you want to understand this better, calculate the residuals of the simple linear regression BodyFat ~ Abdomen. Then make 3 plots and examine them: BodyFat ~ Weight,  BodyFat ~ Abdomen, and residuals(BodyFat ~ Abdomen) ~ Weight.

I'll also note that doing a multiple regression with predictors that are this highly correlated is likely to lead to flawed inferences.

Comment: Notably, fat is less dense than muscle.  So, if you had two people with the exact same body measurements (waist, abdomen, etc.), you'd expect the lighter of the two to have a higher bodyfat percentage.

Comment: @mkt Thanks for the explanation ! much appreciated.

Comment: @KevinTroy Good point! Might even be worth adding that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to @mkt 's answer, which does capture all the most critical mathematical aspects, a few observations:

1. The intercept CI spans from -70 to -33. Assuming that body fat is a percentage, then this means that the baseline amount of fat in the cohort is very variable.
2. If the distribution of BodyFat is left or right tailed then the mean will be skewed relative to the median. This would influence inference of the coefficients
3. Any effect sizes smaller than the mean effect size across variables will have negative coefficients because they provide less effect than the other variables. See the point about standardisation below.
4. the weight is the only coefficient that has CI that do not cross 0, this may reflects inadequate pre-processing rather than anything meaningful at this stage.
5. There is no evidence of any use of height/length to normalise the variables, despite most having a strong relationship with height (tall people/long organisms compared to short people/organisms of the same relative build will have higher weight, larger chest, bigger abdomen, wider hips, thicker thighs and biceps). This could account for a high proportion of the covariance highlighted by @mkt.
6. Correlation between inputs leads to unstable coefficient estimation (the model has no way of knowing the causality). Data reduction (e.g. PCA, PLS) or shrinkage methods (LASSO, Ridge, Elastic Net) could improve the orthogonality of the inputs into the model and improve interpret-ability.
7. Gender also usually influences the covariance of the listed independent variables and so should be included as a factor for a more complete inference.
8. Do you standardise the variables? I don't see that in your code. The variables appear to be on different scales which would also make interpretation of coefficients more difficult.

Comment: If BodyFat is a percentage, then it should probably be modelled using a beta regression instead of a `lm`, shouldn't it?